# How to disable SHIFT modifer for NUMPAD keys?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way to disable shift modifer on numpad on Windows 10?

In some games, I use SHIFT|CTRL|ALT modifiers and on the numpad it automatically switch to LEFT (SHIFT + NUM4), RIGHT (SHIFT + NUM 6) and so on.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

From what I have understood your problem, it is recommended that you can press the button “**Num Lock**”.  I hope my advice is useful to you and if there is any question free to comment.

Comment: This is not at all what the OP was asking.  I have the same problem today.